# Java split returns white spaces in result

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm using the function "split" on this string:

```
p(80,2)
```

I would like to obtain just the two numbers, so this is what I do:

```
String[] split = msg.msgContent().split("[p(,)]")
```

The regex is correct (or at least, I think so) since it splits the two numbers and puts them in the vector "split", but it turns out that this vector has a length of 4, and the first two positions are occupied by white spaces.
In fact, if I print each vector position, this is the result:

```
Split:


80
2
```

I've tried adding \\s to the regex to match with white spaces, but since there are none in my string, it didn't work.

Comment: 1. regex is not correct for split 2. You should not use split

Comment: @anubhava what should I use instead of split?

Comment: Note: they are not white spaces. They are empty strings. There is an empty sting between the beginning of the string and the `p`, and an empty string between the `p` and the `(`.

Comment: By 'vector' you mean array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `split` here, just use a simple regex to extract the digits from your string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(msg.msgContent());
while (m.find()) {
     String number = m.group();
     // add to array
}
```

Note that [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) takes a regex, and the regex you passed doesn't match the pattern you're looking for.

You might want to read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html) of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for more information about the solution above.

Answer (score 2):

`split` accepts a regular expression as parameter, and this is a character class: `[p(,)]`.

Given that your code is splitting on all characters in the class:

`"p(80,2)"` will return an array `{"", "80", "2"}`

I know is not very beautiful:

```
List<String> collect = Pattern.compile("[^\\d]+")
                              .splitAsStream(s)
                              .filter(s -> s.length() > 0)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're splitting on `p` and `(`, the first two characters of your string are resulting in splits. I would split on the comma after replacing the `p`, `(`, and `)`. Like this:

```
String x = "p(80,2)";
String [] y = x.replaceAll("[p()]", "").split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it's not really what you need here, but if you want to use it you can do something like that:

```
"p(80,2)".replace("p(", "").replace(")", "").split(",")
```

Results with

> [80, 2]